# Angular 2: github deployment issue

Tags: angular, github, deployment

I ran the following command: `npm i -g angular-cli-ghpages`

After which I ran the following command: `ng github-pages:deploy`

Why do I always get the following message:

```
The specified command github-pages:deploy is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.
```

Answer (score 0):

ng github-pages:deploy   is removed from latest verion of angular-cli

to do this run :

```
ng build --prod --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY/"
angular-cli-ghpages [OPTIONS]
```

for more info see [angular-cli-ghpages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages)

Answer (score 0):

once you build project with --base-href using

```
ng build --prod --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY/"
```

check if you have all the files in the dist folder.
You would need to go to your repository settings and enable deployment on gh-pages branch. Once that is done go to command prompt and run

```
ngh
```

You can find step by step instructions at
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages